# Read in an integer number

Tags: java

I need someone to give me a clue on how to solve this problem.

Construct an application in Java to:

`Read in an integer number (will always be between 1 - 25) and print the times table corresponding to this number.`

`Input = 8`

And expected output should be below.

`1 * 8 = 8, 2 * 8 = 16`

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, add the tag.

Comment: No, @yotommy no more homework tag. Read its wiki, please.

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far... voted to close.

Answer (score 5):

Read a number: use `new Scanner(System.in)` and its method `nextInt`.

Print the multiplication table: use a for loop and inside use `System.out.println`.

Also, if not already, **definitely do this using an IDE** such as Eclipse. **Do not try to code Java in Notepad**.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Construct an Java application that takes any input and just prints that input back out.

Step 2:

Validate the input to make sure it's an int and then print it out, if not then print out an appropriate warning.

Step 3:

Add checks to see if your input int is within your range, if not print the appropriate warning.

Step 4:

Create a loop and print each result of your multiplication out.

Step 5:

Format your output with String concatenation or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat hesitant to give you ready-made code for this question, so I am instead going to break it down ito steps for you:

1. Read the integer from the command line -- check out `System.In`
2. Verify that the input is indeed an integer (`Integer.parseInt`)
3. Have a `for` loop that iterates from 1-9 and multiplies each number by your input number
4. Output the resulting multiplication at each loop iteration (`System.out.println`)

I realize that you are probably a beginner, but if you try and reason about each individual part separately I think you will not only have an easier time solving the problem, but will also understand something about how code is written in general. Good luck!

Comment: `Int32.TryParse` -- this is not Java.

Comment: Oops, you are right, I meant `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: You can (and should) edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't scared from Google, thousands of answers are there

```
public static void printTable()
   {
        int n, c;
          System.out.println("Enter no.");
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          n = in.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Multiplication table of "+n+" is :-");

          for ( c = 1 ; c <= 25 ; c++ )
             System.out.println(n+"*"+c+" = "+(n*c));
   }
```